# How do you organize your page in php?

Tags: php, html, web

Usually I have the main page (index.php) that include header/footer/menu and the content of the page. The content is changed checking some variable from the GET/POST method: for each condition, I load the page requested.

Somethings like :

```
website/
website/index.php?explore=forum
website/index.php?explore=users
website/index.php?explore=articles
```

and so on...

Now, my website is growing, and I think the best way is to call directly a "index" page for each section; so for example above, this will be traslate as :

```
website/
website/forum/
website/users/
website/articles/
```

that looks better, and is more confortable to manage! The problem is that, if I do this, I need to implement the contour for each zone (that include header/footer/menu).

So I don't know if there are a better strategy and if its convenient. Any suggestions/opinions is welcome! Thanks

Comment: the border of the content, as header/footer/menu :)

Comment: Look at TinyMVC framework, its controllers and routing http://www.tinymvc.com/documentation/index.php/Documentation:Controllers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our projects that are straight PHP (no framework like Symfony or whatever), we definitely have different directories and separate index files for each section, like you say.

But we generally just have one header include file, and one footer file, that applies to every page on the site. That keeps the header and footer consistent, and more manageable.

You can always include the header and footer with a line like

```
<?php include('../includes/head.php'); ?>
```

if you want to keep those files in their own directory. I think we actually have /includes on our include path so our lines just say

```
<?php include('head.php'); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could get the bottom result with the top strategy by doing apache rewrites.  For example, /forum could be re-written to go to www.yoursite.com/index.php?article=forum and so forth.

Here's the complete guide: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Comment: but this doesnt change nothing! just a different url to display :O

Comment: My point was that you don't HAVE to call a specific index page for each example.  Many CMS systems call a single index page and get the content from the database.  It sounds like you've got one file with a giant switch statement of sorts.  This whole strategy thing boils down to what works for you.  If you don't mind overhead and a learning curve, consider a framework.  If you don't want to change much as all, do a rewrite.  If you're looking to physically segregate your code, consider a re-structure using one page per section with includes for header footer.  It's all personal preference.

Answer (score 2):

Check out an MVC framework like Symfony (PHP), Rails (Ruby) or Django (Python).

In the MVC design pattern, you typically have one front controller which handles all the loading. You have models which interact with your data sources, and you have views which define the user interface. Controllers load data via the models, and then pass these to views.

In your example, each section would have a different controller, and different interaction types (the most common being create, list, delete, edit) have different actions.

Comment: Performance-wise, Symfony is TERRIBLE compared to ZendFramework or Code Igniter.  And, much of the Symfony userbase is in Eastern Europe and India, so have fun in the forums if English is your language of choice.....Rails and Django are fine if you don't mind learning an entirely new language....

Answer (score 2):

You could just use .htaccess rewrite rules to redirect those nice-looking URLs to a single `index.php` file.

The only problem is that you'd have to come up with a way of differentiating the URLs to redirect (`website/forum/`, `website/users/`, etc.) from the normal ones (`website/css/`, `website/images/`, etc.).

There are some options:

1. Instead of using `website/[pagename]/`, you could use `website/page/[pagename]/`. Then your regex could just redirect every URL that matches `^/?page/[\w+]/?$` to `index.php?explore=[pagename]`
2. Just explicitly list every page that you want to redirect; use a regex like `^/?[forum|users|articles]/?$`
3. Don't worry about it. If you're only redirecting URLs that don't include a file name, then when you *do* try to reference CSS or images (i.e., URLs that *do* include a filename), it shouldn't be an issue.